# Ubuntu log-in screen freeze when disabling secure boot

Tags: login-screen, secure-boot

I have disabled Secure boot in BIOS.

When I run ubuntu and get to log-in screen everything freezes . I can't write my password neither click on icons..

Comment: This sounds like a bug -- or perhaps you've accidentally changed something in addition to the Secure Boot status in the firmware. If you're certain that you've changed nothing but the Secure Boot status, I recommend you [report it as a bug.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) Be sure to specify the exact make and model of computer you're using, as well as the firmware version.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.